# angular-meteor not working with Meteor 1.3 update - 'uncaughtobject'

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I have just updated the meteor application to Meteor 1.3 but now app is not working and an error is showing 'Uncaught Object'

I tried re installing angular meteor and its not working

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? With this little to go on it could be almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest angular-meteor `1.3.9_2` version?